# MSMQ continues to grow even when there are no messages are in the queue

Tags: msmq

We currently had an issue where MSMQ storage limit has been reached.  We increased the limit which allowed MSMQ to quickly process the rest of the message and resolved our issue.

After the message queue has been emptied, the folder containing message files, message logger and transaction logger remains to be large.

Why does this remain to be large and is there any way to shrink this file?

Could anyone suggest a best practise in maintaining MSMQ files?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

MSMQ purges empty storage files after 6 hours (configurable in registry).
If it doesn't purge then you still have messages.
Common cause is that journaling has been enabled but the journal messages are not being consumed. Quick check is to see if the storage folder has a lot of J*.MQ files.